# Maven deployment to Google Cloud. Does appengine:deploy perform a full clean/build?

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, deployment, google-cloud-platform

I'm deploying an app to Google Cloud, that will run under AppEngine. It's a Maven application that I deploy using:

```
mvn appengine:deploy
```

The [documentation for appengine:deploy](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/maven-reference#appenginedeploy) doesn't explain whether this performs a full clean. What's best practice for deploying an app to AppEngine? Is an explicit clean required? I usually do:

```
mvn clean install
mvn appengine:deploy
```

Answer (score 2):

OK, so looking carefully at the console output for `mvn appengine:deploy`, I see that this performs a new build into the local `target` folder, and then stages the application in a separate folder within `target`:

**Build**

```
[INFO] --------------------------------
[INFO] Building my-project 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------

...

[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [my-project] in [C:\my-project\target\my-project-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [C:\my-project\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [114 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: C:\my-project\target\my-project-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
```

**Stage**

```
[INFO] --- appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.1:deploy (default-cli) @ my-project ---
[INFO] Deleting the staging directory: C:\my-project\target\appengine-staging
[INFO] Staging the application to: C:\my-project\target\appengine-staging
[INFO] Detected App Engine standard environment application.
```

This indicates that a clean isn't necessarily being performed. When I do:

```
 mvn clean install appengine:deploy
```

Then I get different output indicating explicitly that a clean *has* been performed:

```
[INFO] --------------------------------
[INFO] Building my-project 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:3.0.0:clean (default-clean) @ my-project ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\my-project\target
```

...

**Note** - Using `mvn clean install` compiles, packages, and puts the compiled code in your local repository (so that other projects can refer to it). *This may be significant for automated deployments* (`mvn clean package` can be used, but it skips adding the code to the local repository)

So I would advise that the best practice for deployment is:

```
mvn clean install appengine:deploy
```

(**Gotcha when deploying to App Engine** - `mvn appengine:deploy failed to delete one or more files`

If you get this, stop any apps you're debugging or running and close any IDE you're running. The error can occur even if you're debugging a different app that you're not trying to deploy. This is because a local temporary location that's shared across apps is used for some of the deployment staging, and a local running app can lock files located in the temp location.)